# What companions have been for sale for Adventurers League players at Fai Chen’s Fantastical Faire?

Tags: dnd-5e, animal-companions, dnd-adventurers-league

[Fai Chen’s Fantastical Faire](http://dndadventurersleague.org/fantastical-faire/) is described as a trading opportunity for Adventurers League players. It is also [reported](https://www.reddit.com/r/AdventurersLeague/comments/6uv8wl/question_about_fai_chen_cost/) that there are opportunities to buy other consumable items but also “companions”:

> While he does not sell permanent magic items, he does need to feed his
>   ever expanding family. He makes money by selling consumables and other
>   unique things like property, guild memberships, or a companion from
>   his mini menagerie.

What is the range of companions that have been spotted at Fai Chen’s (i.e. are they all beasts?) and what is their price? Most specifically, does there seem to be a pattern in the costs related to the CR of the companion?

Answer (score 4):

It [has been reported](https://www.dndbeyond.com/forums/dungeons-dragons-discussion/d-d-adventurers-league/13820-has-fai-chens-fantastical-faire-actually-ever-sold#c3) that companions are typically for sale at Fai Chen's Fantastical Faire with prices reported ranging from **500gp to 1,000gp**.

- Season 6 had a [Tressym](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Tressym) for sale.
- Season 7 reportedly had a custom goat, otter, and crab for sale. Another noted Fai Chen’s recently had a [giant three toed sloth](https://www.dndbeyond.com/forums/dungeons-dragons-discussion/d-d-adventurers-league/13820-has-fai-chens-fantastical-faire-actually-ever-sold#c8).

Comment: This would be improved by citing the AL season materials; at the moment it's hearsay (and citing hearsay).

Comment: @doppelgreener It shouldn’t be citing hearsay as the person in the post said they saw it themselves. Is Fai Chen’s Faire listed in AL season materials? We have never seen it in them. Our impression was that the Faire varies across conferences and thus can only be determined in person (unless one is an organizer.) Thus, it was assumed our best hope for an answer is from people who have saw items in person (such as described in the link.)

Comment: I see, OK. That changes things. Going by reports might be about the best we can do for that one then after all.

Answer (score 4):

Some of the examples include (with links to images, price at the location of the Fai Chen's where they were offered):

- [Tressym](https://twitter.com/mzsylver/status/832763874994577408): winged cat (1000gp)
- [Xang](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPUac.jpg): a miniature froghemoth that uses the statistics of a giant crab. (50gp, though [another website](https://warhorn.net/events/play-more-games/schedule/sessions/3035a243-93d6-4352-a429-33565aca5cbe) states the price as 500gp)
- [Bakunawa](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxmGO.jpg): a tiny sea serpent that uses the statistics of a flying snake. (50gp, Philippines)
- [Sarimanok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8M6Xc.jpg): a rooster that uses the statistics of a hawk, but with no flying speed. (50gp, Philippines)
- [Kiki Matsing](https://images2.imgbox.com/85/b5/ONMcenc2_o.jpg): a small tarsier that uses the statistics of a baboon. (50gp, Philippines)
- [Banofee the Screaming Goat, Mince the Fainting Goat, Peach the Jumping Goat](https://images2.imgbox.com/85/b5/ONMcenc2_o.jpg): Goats that can be animal companion, familiar, or steed, they scream, faint or jump on the owner's back, at the sight of dinosaurs. (15gp)
- [Alpine Parrot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2af0u_HqKHs&t=55s): blue and yellow parrot that uses the statistics of a raven. (500gp, Kingscon 2017)

All of these companions can be re-summoned using the *find familiar* spell if they get dismissed or drop to 0 hp. The goats can also be re-summoned using *find steed*.

Comment: @NautArch: I have added the location for three. I have also added a couple of more companions to the list.

Comment: Y'know, I have seriously no idea what's even happening in the question, but I clicked on the link to the goats—the idea of goats that freak out around dinosaurs amused me, okay?—to find that it goes to images of the certificates describing the animals in question. That's enough for my +1.